# Is there an Android Studio version specifically for M1 chips that supports Android Emulators?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am using MacBook Air M1 and Android Studio 4.2.1. I can't create Android Emulators on this version because of the M1 chip. I need to download some emulators to test my android apps for both Tablets and normal phones. Any link where I can get these emulators or the Android studio version that can allow me to create emulators?